# How to change the coordinates format according to BED file format using Python?

Tags: python, bioinformatics, fasta

I have two fasta file that I would like to match shorter sequences which is in FileB.fasta to original sequences which is in FileA.fasta to obtain its coordinates or locations. But my output is not in correct format. Can anyone help me?

**FileA.fasta**

```
>chr1:2000-2019
ACGTCGATCGGTCGACGTGC
```

**FileB.fasta**

```
>chr1:2000-2019
GATCGG
```

**FileC.bed**

```
chr1:2000-2019 6 11
```

**Code**

```
from Bio import SeqIO
output_file = open('fileC.bed','w')
for long_sequence_record in SeqIO.parse(open('fileA.fasta'), 'fasta'):
    long_sequence = str(long_sequence_record.seq)
    for short_sequence_record in SeqIO.parse(open('fileB.fasta'), 'fasta'):
        short_sequence = str(short_sequence_record.seq)
        if short_sequence in long_sequence:
            start = long_sequence.index(short_sequence) + 1
            stop = start + len(short_sequence) - 1
           # print short_sequence_record.id, start, stop
            output_line ='%s\t%i\t%i\n' % \
            (short_sequence_record.id,start,stop)
            output_file.write(output_line )
output_file.close()
```

**Desired Output for FileC.bed**

```
chr1 2005 2011
```

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Well, you are adding a 1 to the index at which are finding the shorter sequence -

```
start = long_sequence.index(short_sequence) + 1 <--- notice the +1
```

Don't do that and it should be fine. Also do not do `-1` for the `stop` variable.

You should instead add the starting sequence number from the id.

Example -

```
start = long_sequence.index(short_sequence) + int((short_sequence_record.id.split(':')[1].split('-')[0]))
stop = start + len(short_sequence)
```

For the `id` of the record , if you do not want anything before the `:` then you should split the id at `:` and take the left part (0 index string after split).

Example -

```
output_line ='%s\t%i\t%i\n' % \
        ((short_sequence_record.id.split(':')[0]),start,stop)
        output_file.write(output_line )
```

Comment: I just edit my question. Please have a look. If I use the example above it can't work.

Comment: it will still be counting from 0 I believe, if you want to count for the start,  let me change my code for that.

Comment: Also you are sure that the id would always be like - `chr1:<somenumber>-<someothernumber>` ?

Comment: there are many chr type for example chr2, chr3 etc in a fasta file.

Comment: chr2/3/4... etc is fine, what is mean is that all should be that pattern

Comment: ValueError: invalid literal for int() with base 10: 'chr1'. I have this error.

Comment: The pattern being `<somestring like chr1/2/3/4, etc>:<somenumber>-<someothernumber>`

Answer (score 1):

A more general solution:

1. Take your reference sequence data and make it BLAT-ready with the [relevant UCSC Kent Tools](http://genome.ucsc.edu/FAQ/FAQblat.html#blat3).
2. Do a [BLAT search](http://genome.ucsc.edu/goldenPath/help/blatSpec.html) to align short query strings against the reference data and get a PSL file.
3. [Convert the PSL output](http://bedops.readthedocs.org/en/latest/content/reference/file-management/conversion/psl2bed.html) to BED.